# handling connection timeouts with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have an update thread running in the background of my process, using Linq-to-SQL, which queries the MS SQL Server 2008 R2 DB every 5 minutes looking for records to update.  Periodically I will see an exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout
>   Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the
>   pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the
>   pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in
>   time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server
>   was - [Pre-Login] initialization=1; handshake=15106;  --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
>   timed out

What would be a proper way to retry the operation?

Would I wrap a for loop around the DB operation block like so?

```
public static List<MyRecord> GetUpdatableRecords()
{
    Console.Write("Getting records with null fields...");
    var returnSet = new List<MyRecord>();
    const int retries = 5;
    using (var db = new myDataContext())
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < retries; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                returnSet = db.MyRecords.Where(p => p.businessDate == null).ToList();
                Logging.LogDebug(String.Format("Found {0} records to update!", returnSet.Count));
                break;
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Logging.LogInfo(String.Format("SqlException.Number:     {0}", e.Number));
                Logging.LogInfo(String.Format("SqlException.ErrorCode:  {0}", e.ErrorCode));
                Logging.LogInfo(String.Format("SqlException.HResult:    {0}", e.HResult));
                Logging.LogWarn("SqlException: ", e);
                if (i == retries - 1)
                    throw;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logging.LogWarn("Exception: ", e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnSet;
}
```

Or might I wrap a for loop around the entire data context using block?

```
public static List<MyRecord> GetUpdatableRecords()
{
    Console.Write("Getting records with null fields...");
    var returnSet = new List<MyRecord>();
    const int retries = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < retries; i++)
    {
        using (var db = new myDataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                returnSet = db.MyRecords.Where(p => p.businessDate == null).ToList();
                Logging.LogDebug(String.Format("Found {0} records to update!", returnSet.Count));
                break;
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Logging.LogInfo(String.Format("SqlException.Number:     {0}", e.Number));
                Logging.LogInfo(String.Format("SqlException.ErrorCode:  {0}", e.ErrorCode));
                Logging.LogInfo(String.Format("SqlException.HResult:    {0}", e.HResult));
                Logging.LogWarn("SqlException: ", e);
                if (i == retries - 1)
                    throw;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logging.LogWarn("Exception: ", e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you poll every 5 minutes and from error it seems like opening the connection is expensive, do not use using with your datacontext.

Rather, Implement IDisposable in your class where you have this method, make your datacontext a private member of class and within Dispose() method, just dispose off your datacontext which will in turn release the database connection as well when the instance of your class will go out of scope.

Regards
Kajal